# Autocad Change Properties for All Object

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, design, technical-drawing

Does anyone know how to change the Vertex X and Vertex Y value for all of the dots? Because some of the red dots has a different vertex X and Y value which also causes the shape to be slightly different.

I know that by clicking each of the object's properties one by one to change the vertex x and Y individually but it's a tedious task since I have a **lot of red dots**. Is there a way to highlight all of the red dots and change all of the red dot's Vertex X and Y value without clicking each of the object individually to change the values (Tedious Task) ?

I will really appreciate any help to avoid tedious task. Thank you and have a nice day :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Anyone,please help :) ?

Comment: are the dot part of a spline or a polyline? or are they just individual nodes?